# Find the condition number of $A$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, numerical-methods, numerical-linear-algebra, condition-number

> Find the condition number of
>
> $$A = \begin{bmatrix} 
> 0 & 0 & -10^4 & 0  \\ 
> 0 & 0 & 0 & -10  \\ 
> 0 & 10^{-3} & 0 & 0 \\
> 10^{-2}& 0& 0& 0 \\
> \end{bmatrix}$$

The way they want us to do it is to find $\|A\|$, then $\|A^{-1}\|$ and then $\|A\| \|A^{-1}\|$. However, I can't manage to find $\|A\|$. I've tried using Lagrange multipliers, but I get four different $\lambda_i$ for each $x_i$ when I try to solve $\max\limits_{x \neq 0} \frac{||Ax||}{||x||}$.

Comment: I've never heard of using Lagrange multipliers for this; what exactly is your method for finding $\|A\|$?  Do you know about eigenvalues?  What about singular values?  Are you supposed to get an exact answer or an approximate (decimal) answer?

Comment: I solve $\max\limits_{x \neq 0} \frac{||Ax||}{||x||}$. We haven't done eigenvalues or singular values yet. We can check on matlab. From my check we need the exact answer. @Omnomnomnom

Comment: "I can't manage to find $\|A\|$" - you neglected to mention which matrix norm you're using. There are many of them, of which I know four to be popular.

Answer (score 1):

Our optimization problem can be framed as minimize $\|Ax\|^2$ subject to $\|x\|^2 = 1$.  In other words, we have
$$
f(x) = 10^{-4}x_1^2 + 10^{-6} x_2^2 +  10^8x_3^2 + 100\,x_4^2\\
g(x) = x_1^2 + x_2^2 + x_3^2 + x_4^2 = 1
$$
Setting $f' - \lambda g' = 0$ yields
$$
(1 - 10^{-4}\lambda)x_1 = 0\\
(1 - 10^{-6}\lambda) x_2 = 0\\
(1 - 10^8\lambda)x_3 = 0\\
(1 - 100 \lambda )x_4 = 0
$$
This should indeed lead to **four** solutions for $\lambda$, and the corresponding vectors $x = (1,0,0,0); x = (0,1,0,0)$ and so on.

Once we have the $\lambda_i$, we have to **check** each of the corresponding solutions.  The greatest value for $f(x)$ comes from $\lambda = 10^{-8}$, for which we attain $f(x) = 10^8$.

Thus, the maximum is $\|Ax\| = \sqrt{10^8} = 10^4$.